# Bazel: running tests against different Python versions

Tags: bazel, bazel-python

I am getting to know `Bazel`, and I would like to be able to test the same codebase against several python versions, mostly for the purposes of safe transition to a new one.

I'm using `python_register_toolchain` to specify my python interpreter. I tried creating two different interpreters, but then I cannot run the same `py_test` target twice with different interpreters.

Is there a way to solve this? Or is there a better way of checking the compatibility with the next python version before transitioning?